# How does "-float" works?

Tags: python

I have just seen a code in my homework. It says `result=-float("inf")`. I don't really understand what `-float` means.

Comment: `float(x)` returns the numeric value of `x`, which you can then use in conjunction with arithmetic operations, such as `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`.

Comment: `float(...)` is a method in python to convert an integer to a floating-point (i.e. a decimal) number  - so, `- float(...)` will return the negative value of said number - and assign it to `result` ... Now, the curveball here is that the code you mentioned is passing a `string` value as a parameter.  `inf` represents infinity in this case, so `result` is basically given a negative infinitive value (which is not a number)

Comment: It just negates the result of the `float()` call. Like you could say `-(1 + 2)` and it would result in `-3`, `-` is just a unary operator in this case. You could also interpret the line to be equivalent to `result = float("inf") * -1.0`

Comment: @blurfus Please don't post answers in the comments. You're mostly correct, but you got some details wrong: 1) `float` is a type, not a function, and not a method in Python terminology; 2) it accepts more than just integers; 3) [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) is a different thing; 4) `string` should be `str`; 5) "parameter" should be "argument"; 5) infinity is a number in this context (e.g. `isinstance(-float("inf"), numbers.Number)` -> `True`). If you'd posted an answer, you (or someone else) would be able to edit and fix these.

Comment: @wjandrea `float` is a type but `float(...)` is a function/method

Comment: @blurfus No, `float(...)` is a *call*, syntactically. `float` is a *callable* type. And in Python, the term [*method*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method) refers to functions defined on a class, like `list.append` for example.

Comment: @wjandrea Hmmm, while you might be correct, there is also this (which is what is commonly used): https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=float%20function#float  and https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=float

Comment: @blurfus Ah yeah, that page title is misleading. If you read the first paragraph, it says *"The Python interpreter has a number of functions **and types** built into it ..."*, and for `float`, it says `class float`. I guess callable types are included for convenience and to avoid confusing newbies.

Answer (score 0):

[`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) is a built-in function in Python that returns a floating point number constructed from a number or string.

`float("inf")` returns the floating-point representation of positive infinity, so `-float("inf")` is how you can get negative infinity.

There are a number of [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) in Python that it pays to be familiar with.

Comment: Which works because `-` is the [unary minus](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) and doesn't require a second operand.

Comment: Beside the point, but `float` is actually a type, not a function

Answer (score 0):

It's not `-float`, it's `-float(...)`.

`float(x)` makes a floating-point number from `x`. Here, `float("inf")` represents positive infinity, so the `-` negates it and you get negative infinity.

Another way to get negative infinity is `float("-inf")`.

For reference, see [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in the docs. A call is more tightly binding than unary negation.